# How to use bootstrap modal for edit the data using ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bootstrap-modal, ejs

I am working on E-commerce project using nodejs,mongoDb at backend and ejs for frontend . I want to edit the user and order data . So I want to use bootstrap modal for edit the data . But I am confused about how I inject modal and submit the data to the database .

How I can submit the data to Db ?

**allorders.ejs (updated...)**

```js
<%- include("../partials/header") %> <%- include("../partials/navbar") %>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3 class="text-center mt-2">All Orders</h3>
  <table class="table table-bordered border-primary mt-4 mb-3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Order Updated Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <% for(let order of allOrders ){ %>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order._id %></td>
        <td><%= order.date %></td>
        <td><%= order.updatedAt %></td>
        <td><%= order.status %></td>
        <td><%= order.amount %></td>
        <td className="bg-secondary">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
          >
            Update
          </button>

          <!-- Modal For Edit Status-->
          <div
            class="modal fade"
            id="staticBackdrop"
            data-bs-backdrop="static"
            data-bs-keyboard="false"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                    Update Order Status
                  </h5>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn-close"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  ></button>
                </div>
                <form
                  class="m-5"
                  id="form"
                  action="/admin/<%= currentUser._id %>/order/<%=order._id%>?_method=PATCH"
                  method="POST"
                >
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="orderId" class="form-label">Order ID</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="orderId"
                      disabled
                      value="<%= order._id %>"
                    />
                    <label class="form-label">Current Status</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      disabled
                      value="<%= order.status %>"
                    />
                    <div class="mb-4">
                      <label for="updateStatus" class="form-label"
                        >Update Staus
                      </label>
                      <select
                        class="form-select form-control"
                        name="status"
                        value="status"
                      >
                        <option name="Processing" value="Processing">
                          Processing
                        </option>
                        <option name="Prepared" value="Prepared">
                          Prepared
                        </option>
                        <option name="Dispatched" value="Dispatched">
                          Dispatched
                        </option>
                        <option name="Delivered" value="Delivered">
                          Delivered
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save">
                    Save Status
                  </button>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                  >
                    Cancle
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% } %>
  </table>
</div>
<%- include("../partials/footer") %>
```

**routes**

```js
router.get("/admin/:id/allorders", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allOrders = await Order.find({}).sort({ date: -1 });
    res.render("admin/allOrders", { allOrders });
  } catch (error) {
    req.flash("error", "Cannot Find Orders");
    res.render("error");
  }
});

router.patch("/admin/:id/order/:orderId", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.orderId, req.body);
    req.flash("success", "Order Updated Successfully");
    res.redirect(`/admin/${req.params.id}/allorders`);
  } catch (error) {
    req.flash("error", "Cannot Update Order");
    res.render("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: EJS is a templating language used to build dynamic HTML on the server. What you want is to either a) submit a form or b) intercept the form's submission event and send the data via ajax. Which is it?

Comment: Can you please explain both options ?

Comment: The first is basic form submission, where the brower will send a GET or POST request to the URL in the `action` attribute, then navigate to the server's reply. The second is a background request where no navigation takes place, the server's response is then handled by more JS code. Note that this is HTTP 101 and stackoverflow isn't really the place for beginner tutorials.

Comment: I don't want to navigate to another page for updating only one place . So I think using bootstrap modal ajax request is better option for me .

Comment: Ok, then start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch or google "fetch post form data"

Comment: I create the modal and update route also but only first order gets update . Others order not updating .

Comment: All modals shows ID and Status of first order .

Comment: Can you show your fetch code? Just add it to your question.

Comment: I fetched all orders but when I click update button for updating status of any order that time modal shows first order only .

Comment: Your modals all have `id="staticBackdrop"`, which is already invalid HTML because IDs are supposed to be unique. Your button has `data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"` which will simply open the first modal, always. The easy way to avoid this is to use `order._id` as the id and in the button.

Comment: If I remove `data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"` then modal not gets popup .

Comment: when modal opens it shows details about first order only

Comment: I know, it's because *all your buttons open the **first** modal*. And nobody said anything about removing it. In the button, replace `#staticBackdrop` with `#<%= order._id %>` and in the modal div, use `id="<%= order._id %>"`

Comment: It also not working  `data-bs-target="#<%= order._id %>" `   `id="<%= order._id %>"`

Comment: How is it "not working"? What happens when you click a button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233657/discussion-between-prathamesh-mungekar-and-chris-g).

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/og5hyvas/ it uses `id1` and `id2`.

Comment: I check the code from Devtools it showing correct values but modal shows another values .

Comment: Please post example HTML (as it appears in the browser, press Ctrl+U to see the final HTML)

Comment: codeshare link [https://codeshare.io/8pyknv]

Comment: (https://codeshare.io/8pyknv)

Comment: @ChrisG did you check code ?

Comment: I just checked the code, yes. Maybe an id isn't supposed to start with a number? Try adding a letter or two. Like `data-bs-target="#order<%= order._id %>"` (same for the modal id, obviously)